# YouTube API Search Video return Playlist item

Tags: google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I got a "kind" `youtube#playlist` in result when I made this request even if I set "type" to "video" value to return only videos:

[YouTube Search.List](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.search.list?part=snippet&maxResults=1&q=Demi%20Lovato%20Sorry%20Not%20Sorry&type=video&_h=1&)

I got this:

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchListResponse",
  "etag": "\"_gJQceDMxJ8gP-8T2HLXUoURK8c/9VWjbEaR6eNH0YMYb_Dbc2fPG70\"",
  "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
  "regionCode": "FR",
  "pageInfo": {
    "totalResults": 1000000,
    "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
    {
      "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
      "etag": "\"_gJQceDMxJ8gP-8T2HLXUoURK8c/YNUnc9nKZyCAIp2V_uVZhyg5tC0\"",
      "id": {
        "kind": "youtube#playlist",
        "playlistId": "PLJ49NV73ttrutlLqBBYmYyvPxzRft9q4s"
      },
      "snippet": {
        "publishedAt": "2017-12-08T20:07:17.000Z",
        "channelId": "UC4PooiX37Pld1T8J5SYT-SQ",
        "title": "Esther Povitsky, Spicy Candy Showdown & More! GMM #1255",
        "description": "Comedian Esther Povitsky helps us figure out the weird things people google, we boil your favorite songs down to their essence, we taste test the spiciest candies, and more!",
        "thumbnails": {
          "default": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_1HrNThkeKo/default.jpg",
            "width": 120,
            "height": 90
          },
          "medium": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_1HrNThkeKo/mqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 320,
            "height": 180
          },
          "high": {
            "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/_1HrNThkeKo/hqdefault.jpg",
            "width": 480,
            "height": 360
          }
        },
        "channelTitle": "Good Mythical Morning",
        "liveBroadcastContent": "none"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Any idea why ?

Comment: Setting `type` to `video` is correct, though. Because if you set `videoType` to any valid value and `type` to something other than `video`, you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

Youtube api [Search](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search)

> A search result contains information about a YouTube video, channel,
>   or playlist that matches the search parameters specified in an API
>   request. While a search result points to a uniquely identifiable
>   resource, like a video, it does not have its own persistent data.

Search.list will return results for Videos, channels and playlists.

As to why the query explorer is return playlists thats a bug its not applying all the parameters.   [issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73094689)

Comment: Yes, seems to be a bug on this specific "q" parameter. Thank you for creating the ticket issue.